# Why is an IV needed when encrypting a private SSH key

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, ssh, key-generation, asymmetric

Given a password protected private key like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,D54228DB5838E32589695E83A22595C7

3+Mz0A4wqbMuyzrvBIHx1HNc2ZUZU2cPPRagDc3M+rv+XnGJ6PpThbOeMawz4Cbu
lQX/Ahbx+UadJZOFrTx8aEWyZoI0ltBh9O5+ODov+vc25Hia3jtayE51McVWwSXg
wYeg2L6U7iZBk78yg+sIKFVijxiWnpA7W2dj2B9QV0X3ILQPxbU/cRAVTd7AVrKT
    ... etc ...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

One can tell that the base64 encoded IV is specified in the header.

I do understand the importance of IV:s when it comes to "sniffable" traffic like traffic over 802.11*, etc, but I can't get my head around why an IV is needed when encrypting a private SSH key (as these are never transmitted over the wire).

Would somebody care to elaborate why the IV is needed in these cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `CBC` mode of symmetric cipher requires `IV` to decrypt the encoded key, as explained in the common picture of Cipher Block Chaining (CBC):

[image: Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) decryption].

The IV is not part of the passphrase, because it is not a secret. It was generated as a random number, but you can decrypt the key itself only with the knowledge of this IV.

> Given a password protected private key like:

And note that it is not a password, but pass-phrase, which makes it basically the source data for key encryption key.

Comment: I do see your point, but my question was meant to be interpreted as "why not use a null IV" (as this data never hits the wire)? Is the random factor really needed when the key is only stored locally? But perhaps it even saves us one block of processing?

Comment: Using fixed IV (null for example) would degrade the cipher and make it less vulnerable to some alternative to the rainbow tables. Similar way as the passwords are protected with a salt, I guess (I don't have specific attack in my mind, but there is space to misuse).
The key should not leak from your computer, but when it does you should make sure that it will not get encrypted by other people. Also only part of the key might leak and then having more entropy (IV) is a good thing.